# Linear mixed effect model with repeated measures using lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, blocking, linear

**Background**
I think I am close to the error structure I want for random effects but not sure about some parts of it. I am carrying an experiment on wheat plots in a field to measure the increase in aphid numbers over time.

**Experimental design and coding for predictors**
I put 4 populations of aphids into a wheat plot and subjected them to four different cage treatments (`Cage_treatment`). I measured the number of aphids before they were subjected to the treatments and after e.g. two time periods, before and after(`Time`). I repeated this in many wheat plots within a field. Three wheat plots are part of different three types of crop rotation (`Rotation`). These 3 plots x 3 crop rotations equal a block. There are four blocks in total. I am measuring aphid numbers per tiller (`Total_per_tiller`).

The effects I am interested in e.g. fixed effects is how the `Total_per_tiller` aphid numbers change over `Time`, how this differs for each `Cage_treatment` and how the `Rotation` effects this.

**Fixed and Random effects**

Fixed effects:

- Cage_treatment,
- Rotation,
- Time,

Random effects:

- Plot ID,
- Block,

This is the following code for my maximal model:

```
model <- lmer(Total_per_tiller~Cage_treatment*Rotation*Time + (Time|PlotID) + 
              (1|Block/Rotation), REML=FALSE)
```

Does this look right?

Answer (score 1):

In your model `Rotation` is both a fixed effect slope and a random effect nested in `Block` in here: `(1|Block/Rotation)`. If you wanted `Rotation` to be a random slope in `Block` you would have to define it as `(1 + Rotation|Block)`. What `(1|Block/Rotation)` means is: `(1|Block) + (1|Block:Rotation)`, i.e. a random intercept for `Block` and a random intercept for `Rotation` nested in `Block`.

Check also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306472/translating-proc-mixed-to-lmer-sas-to-r/27306613#27306613) on SO or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126742/specification-of-mixed-model). More information on defining models in lme4 you can find in an article by [Bates et al. (in press)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf) or in this [online book](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf).

Btw, why you don't want REML method for estimation?