# Mixed model (Multilevel) with two INDEPENDENT Random Effects [lmer]

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I like to estimate a mixed model with two Random Effects, that are independent of each other and among themselves.

I use Panel data with a nested structure (counties $j$ nested within regions $i$). The error component should decompose in the following way:

$$E_{ijt} = \alpha_i + \mu_{ij} + e_{ijt}$$

$\alpha_i$ is an unobservable region specific time-invariant effect (normal distributed)

$\mu_{ij}$ is a nested effect of  county $j$ within region $i$ (normal distributed)

$e_{ijt}$ is a remainder disturbance (normal distributed)

I read somewhere that "lmer" is capable to fit such specifications with idenpendent Random Effects.

`lmer(y~.... + (1|region) + (1|county)`

Is the lmer-model adequate for my task?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `lme4` should be fine in here. The formula you are asking is:

`y ~ 1 + (1|region) + (1|region:county)`

because in model you described `country` is nested in `region`.

For an extended description and examples see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126742/specification-of-mixed-model/126752#126752), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet).